# One to one Private chat Using socket and Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, node.js, redis, socket.io, laravel-5.1

**I am using Laravel5.1 Socket.io and Redis, Mysql**

I want to create one to one chat for the user using Socket.

---------Server Side--------

```js
var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);
    var Redis = require('ioredis');
    var redis = new Redis();
    http.listen(3000, function(){
        console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
    });

    io.on('connection', function(socket) {

        socket.on('message', function(data, cb){
            socket.to(data.destId).emit('message', {'desc':data.message, 'destId':socket.id,'userProfile':data.userProfile});
            cb('success sending message');
        });

        socket.on('join', function(data, cb){
            socket.join(data.user);
            cb('success joining');
        });

        socket.on('bye', function(user){
            socket.broadcast.to(user).emit('bye', socket.id);
        })
    });
```

**I would like to handle the message that is not delivered to the user and I would also like to show whether the message is read by recipient or not**

If I am storing all the message in Database(Mysql). There will be a lot IO operation. One thing could be store into Redis or Memcached. can You suggest
me the efficient way to do that.

Help me to configure Redis to store the data so that I can use from the socket.js file ( It is in the root directory and it contains the server side code of socekt.io).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effecient way would be using redis

```
redis.subscribe('test-channel', function () {
    console.log('message has been received');
});
```

first registering channel in laravel and make it available throught redis in node
of you can just sent user id from client emit and also check the if the id has been changed by thug user or not buy calling an event where ther server side would get his id wherer he cnt change then sent it from redis to node and check if the both id is equal then he meant to recirve the message